# Why won't this jQuery Data example work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is MADDENING.

Here is my html:

```
<td><a class="opener" data-dialogid="dialog1"><%= responsibility.user.email %></a></td>
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
$('.opener').mouseover(function() {
    alert($(this).data("dialogid"));
    return false;
});
```

I have tried every possible iteration of that "alert" line above. I am basically trying to pass a data value to my Javascript. But it seems impossible. I am pulling my hair out, this is really, really frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `data-dialogid`, but it's looking for `data-digitalid`, make them match :)

For example:

```
$('.opener').mouseover(function() {
    alert($(this).data("dialogid"));
    return false;
});
```

Also note that this only works in jQuery 1.4.3+, you would need `.attr("data-dialogid")` before that.

Comment: +1. Did not know about the data-prefix thingumajig until now.

Comment: Thanks Nick. That was pretty stupid of me. However, I'm still getting "undefined" in my alert, even after fixing. So it still isn't getting that value from my html.

Comment: @AKWF are you sure you're using jQuery 1.4.4 (or 1.4.3, but if you're using 1.4.3 you need to upgrade anyway)?

Comment: Pointy, maybe you didn't see the comment above where I talked about how stupid I am. Problem solved. +1s all around.